# Check if the Snake bangs into itself in game

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm writing Snake in C++, using OpenGL and GLFW. I'm trying to implement a feature where the game exits, when the snakes head crashes into its body. 
Here are the move() and CrashCheck() functions of the Snake class that I wrote.
x_pos is a floating point array that stores the x_coordinate of a segment of the snake body. y_pos does the same with the y_coordinate. length is the number of body segments in the snake, and increases when the snake eats food(not yet implemented). x_speed and y_speed store the speeds of the segments along the axis. The snake can never move along both the axes simultaneously; Also, `float MAX_S =  0.00075;`. I've included my draw() function as well. And Fix_Snake_x and Fix_Snake_y are functions that realign the segments of the snake (because they kept separating and causing havoc with the game). I know it's a stupid way to correct the problem, so if you can suggest fixes in the move() function, that would helpful.

```
void draw(float win_aspect)
  {
    for(int a = 0; a < length; a++)
      {
        Fix_Snake_y();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex2f(x_pos[a],y_pos[a]);
        glVertex2f((x_pos[a]+0.05),y_pos[a]);
        glVertex2f((x_pos[a]+0.05),y_pos[a]-0.05);
        glVertex2f(x_pos[a],y_pos[a] - 0.05);
        glEnd();
        Fix_Snake_x();
      }
  } 

void move()
  {
      for(int a = length ; a >= 0; a--)
        {
          if(a > 0)
            {
              if(x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a-1] && x_speed[a] < 0)
                {
                  x_pos[a] += -MAX_S;
                  Fix_Snake_y();
                  Fix_Snake_x();
                  if(x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a - 1])
                  {
                     x_speed [a] = 0;
                     if(y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1])
                     {
                          y_speed[a] = MAX_S;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                           y_speed[a] = -MAX_S;
                     }
                   }
                }
              if(x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a-1] && x_speed[a] > 0)
                {
                  x_pos[a] += MAX_S;
                  Fix_Snake_y();
                  Fix_Snake_x();
                  if(x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a - 1])
                    {
                      x_speed [a] = 0;
                      if(y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1])
                       {
                          y_speed[a] = MAX_S;
                       }
                      else
                        {
                          y_speed[a] = -MAX_S;
                        }
                    }
                }
              if(y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1] && y_speed[a] > 0)
                {
                  y_pos[a] += MAX_S;
                  Fix_Snake_y();
                  Fix_Snake_x();
                  if(y_pos[a] >= y_pos[a-1])
                    {
                      y_speed[a] = 0;
                      if(x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a-1])
                        {
                          x_speed[a] = -MAX_S;
                        }
                      if(x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a-1])
                        {
                          x_speed[a] = MAX_S;
                        }
                    }
                }
              if(y_pos[a] >= y_pos[a-1] && y_speed[a] < 0)
                {
                  y_pos[a] += -MAX_S;
                  Fix_Snake_y();
                  Fix_Snake_x();
                  if(y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1])
                    {
                      y_speed[a] = 0;
                      if(x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a-1])
                        {
                          x_speed[a] = -MAX_S;
                        }
                      if(x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a-1])
                        {
                          x_speed[a] = MAX_S;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }


          if(a == 0)
                {
                  x_pos[0] += x_speed[0];
                  y_pos[0] += y_speed[0];
                  Fix_Snake_y();
                  Fix_Snake_x();
                }
             CrashCheck();
            }
      }
      void CrashCheck()
      {
        for(int a = 1; a < length; a++)
          {
            if(y_speed[0] > 0 && y_speed[a] == 0)
              {
                if(x_pos[0] < x_pos[a] && x_pos[0] < x_pos[a] + 0.05)
                  {
                    if(y_pos[0] < y_pos[a] && y_pos[0] > y_pos[a] - 0.05)
                      {
                        exit(0);
                      }
                  }
              }
            else if(y_speed[0] < 0 && y_speed[a] == 0)
              {
                if(x_pos[0] > x_pos[a] && x_pos[0] < x_pos[a] + 0.05)
                  {
                    if(y_pos[0] < y_pos[a] && y_pos[0] > y_pos[a] - 0.05)
                      {
                        exit(0);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
void Fix_Snake_x()
  {
    for(int a = 1; a<length; a++)
      {
        if(a > 0)
          {
            if(x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a-1] - 0.05)
              {
                x_pos[a] = x_pos[a-1] - 0.05;
              }
            if(x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a -1] + 0.05)
              {
                x_pos[a] = x_pos[a-1] + 0.05;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  void Fix_Snake_y()
  {
    for(int a = 1; a < length; a++)
          {
            if(a > 0)
              {
                if(y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1] - 0.05)
                  {
                    y_pos[a] = y_pos[a-1] - 0.05;
                  }
                if(y_pos[a] >= y_pos[a-1] + 0.05)
                  {
                    y_pos[a] = y_pos[a-1] + 0.05;
                  }
              }
          }
  }
```

Edit:
New move function

```
for(int a = 0; a < length; a++)
        {
            if(a > 0)
              {
                if(x_speed[a] < 0 && x_pos[a] >= x_pos[a-1])
                  {
                    x_pos[a] += x_speed[a];
                    if(x_pos[a] == x_pos[a-1])
                      {
                        y_speed[a] = y_speed[a-1];
                        x_speed[a] = 0;
                        continue;
                      }
                  }
                if(x_speed[a] > 0 && x_pos[a] <= x_pos[a-1])
                  {
                    x_pos[a] += x_speed[a];
                    if(x_pos[a] == x_pos[a-1])
                      {
                        y_speed[a] = y_speed[a-1];
                        x_speed[a] = 0;
                        continue;
                      }
                  }
                if(y_speed[a] > 0 && y_pos[a] <= y_pos[a-1])
                  {
                    y_pos[a] += y_speed[a];
                    if(y_pos[a] == y_pos[a-1])
                      {
                        x_speed[a] = x_speed[a-1];
                        y_speed[a] = 0;
                      }
                  }
                if(y_speed[a] < 0 && y_pos[a] >= y_pos[a-1])
                  {
                    y_pos[a] += y_speed[a];
                    if(y_pos[a] == y_pos[a-1])
                      {
                        x_speed[a] = x_speed[a-1];
                        y_speed[a] = 0;
                      }
                  }
              }
            else
              {
                x_pos[0] += x_speed[0];
                y_pos[0] += y_speed[0];
              }
        }
```

Is causing a few problems. The snake breaks it there are too many simultaneous turns. Only the first two blocks remain in motion

Comment: So is your question, "Where's the problem in my code that causes the snake's body to separate?"

Comment: Belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would store a `std::set` with all the invalid coordinates that the snake can't go to. That would include:

- the border of the "playground"
- obstacles
- the snake's body

Then for each move of the snake, considering the x/y speed(s) I would first try to `InsertLocation` into `CInvalidPlaces`, if that returns `true` then I can step there, if `false` then the snake's just about to hit a wall, the border or it's own body and the "game" can finish. Here's the code for that:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> tInvalidLocation;

struct ltSeCmp
{
    bool operator()(tInvalidLocation s1, tInvalidLocation s2) const
    {
        if (s1.first == s2.first) return s1.second > s2.second;
        return s1.first > s2.first;
    }
};

typedef set<tInvalidLocation, ltSeCmp> tInvalidLocations;

class CInvalidPlaces
{
private:
    tInvalidLocations mInvalid; //this set will hold all the invalid locations for the snake to go to
public:
    bool InsertLocation(tInvalidLocation iLoc)
    {
        if (mInvalid.find(iLoc) != mInvalid.end()) return false;    //check if the location is already in the set
        //we survived.. it's safe to go there :)
        mInvalid.insert(iLoc);
        return true;
    }
    bool RemoveLocation(tInvalidLocation iLoc)
    {
        if (mInvalid.find(iLoc)== mInvalid.end()) return false;
        mInvalid.insert(iLoc);
        return true;
    }
};
```

What you will have to do additionally is :

- initially add the margins, all the obstacles, and all the positions of the snake just as they are from where the snake starts
- modify the move routine, so that when the snake moves, it also has to remove from `CInvalidPlaces` it's tail using `RemoveLocation`
- after you implement the "enlargement" of the snake you'll also have to add to `CInvalidPlaces` the extra segment.

If need be, you can find in the following places extra information about an `stl::set` :

- [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html)
- [CPP.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)

HTH,
JP

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you use a dynamic container to hold the coordinates of the snakes's body.  This allows to you take the coordinate of the snakes new position and search the container for the coordinates.  If the point is found, the snake has run into itself.

Similarly you can have container for points of walls and blocks and other entities that is not part of the board.

An alternative is to use a grid data structure (or matrix), and place values in it representing the snakes body and other obstacles.

Comment: The container is dynamic. It stores the current positions of the snake body. The search method is a good idea but the problem is that a search for exact coordinates would never give an exact match. Perhaps I shol try matching coordinates of the centre of the block ?

Comment: @viraj, your main problem with not being able to get an exact match is you haven't separated the model and view.  If you used a grid, the snake would either be in it or not.  The floating point coordinates should only be used to _display_ the snake, not for game logic.  That would also help your separation issue.

Comment: @viraj:  The grid should not have floating point values.  Normalize to some integral value.  As Karl said, you need some functionality that maps (draws) the grid onto the screen.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews
I should use the integer coordinates to move the snake as well, right ?

Comment: @viraj: Historically, the snake moves around on a grid.  The grid has an *integral* (not floating point) number of rows and columns.  The snake's head and other body segments occupy one cell each.  Until you get all the algorithms working treat the display as a grid of squares.  It may be poor quality graphics; but those can be improved after all the algorithms are working correctly.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews that's what I've done. But the snake breaks, when there are too may rapid turns. Should I include a Fix_Snake() function ?